# Error while unit testing HttpClientModule (Angular 4.3+)

Tags: angular

I'm exploring the new Angular HttpClientModule and running into an inexplicable error. The module is new enough that I can't yet find any useful information about how to unit test, and the official documentation doesn't have any examples.

The app contains a service with one method, which passes a URL to `http.get`. When I call this method in a browser context (aka `ng serve`), the http call executes normally. When called in the context of a unit test, I get the following error:

`TypeError: You provided 'undefined' where a stream was expected. You can provide an Observable, Promise, Array, or Iterable.`

This is a minimal app generated with Angular CLI. Here's the pertinent code:

**app.module.ts:**

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [AppComponent],
  imports: [BrowserModule, HttpClientModule],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

**app.component.ts:**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { TestService } from './test.service'

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css'],
  providers: [TestService]
})
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'app';

  constructor(private testSvc: TestService) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.testSvc.executeGet('http://www.example.com');
  }
}
```

**test.service.ts:**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';

@Injectable()
export class TestService {
  constructor(private http:HttpClient) {}

  executeGet(url:string) {
    this.http.get(url)
      .subscribe(
        data => console.log('success', data),
        error => console.log('error', error)
    );
  }
}
```

**test.service.spec.ts:**

```
import { HttpClient, HttpHandler } from '@angular/common/http';
import { TestBed, inject } from '@angular/core/testing';
import { TestService } from './test.service';

describe('TestService', () => {
  beforeEach(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      providers: [HttpClient, HttpHandler, TestService]
    });
  });

  it('should executeGet', inject([TestService], (svc: TestService) => {
    expect(svc.executeGet).toBeDefined();
    // this is where the 'undefined' error occurs
    svc.executeGet('http://www.example.com'); 
  }));
});
```

Any guidance or pointers greatly appreciated.

Comment: Do You really need a real HttpClientModule? According to [documentation](https://angular.io/guide/http#testing-http-requests) - the HTTP backend needs to be mocked as part of good testing practice.

Comment: @AleksandrPetrovskij I've read the available documentation. It's quite thin, and HttpClientModule is young enough that there isn't much third-party content available about how to use it. I ran into other issues when trying to use HttpClientTestingModule, but chose not to include them in this post in order to keep it focused on the 'undefined' error. 

Regardless,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Import of HttpClientModule missing

[Here is the working example on plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/InyCCcl74EzzDXGo2owY)

```
describe('TestService', () => {
  beforeEach(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      imports: [HttpClientModule],
      providers: [TestService]
    });
  });

  it('should executeGet', () => {
    const testService = TestBed.get(TestService);

    expect(testService.executeGet).toBeDefined();
    testService.executeGet('http://www.example.com');
  }));
});
```

Comment: Thank you for the example. I appreciate it. 

That said, it doesn't help me understand the error, nor why it appears to be impossible to unit test without mocks. I understand why mocking is a good idea in tests, but not why the HTTP call fails in the absence of mocks, which is the crux of my question.

Comment: I think import of *HttpClientModule* missing, [example](http://plnkr.co/edit/InyCCcl74EzzDXGo2owY)

Comment: That's it! Thanks again, Aleksandr. If you want to update your answer or post a different one, I'll accept it gladly.

Answer (score 3):

Recently I experienced exact same issue where the error message says:

`TypeError: You provided 'undefined' where a stream was expected. You can provide an Observable, Promise, Array, or Iterable.`

For me the source of this error was not using **HttpInterceptor** properly. If you are also providing custom **HttpInterceptor** make sure you properly use it. In following code snippet notice how I missed returning `Observable, Promise, Array, or Iterable` if error status is other than 401. By default `undefined` is returned by the `intercept` method instead of `Observable, Promise, Array, or Iterable` so angular is complaining about that.

```
intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
    return next.handle(req).catch(err => {
      if(err instanceof HttpErrorResponse) {
        if(err.status === 401) {
          this.store.dispatch(this.authAction.unauthorized(err));
          return Observable.throw(err);
        }
      }
    })
  }
```

and the fix to is was following code snippet.

```
intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
    return next.handle(req).catch(err => {
      if(err instanceof HttpErrorResponse) {
        if(err.status === 401) {
          this.store.dispatch(this.authAction.unauthorized(err));
        }
      }
      return Observable.throw(err); //Actually this line of code
    })
  }
```

Comment: I'm not using an HttpInterceptor. As I mentioned before, `TestService.executeGet` works when running in a browser context but fails in a unit test. There's something about the environment difference that seems to be causing the problem.

Comment: how do you unit test the interceptor. Do you have a sample to share?