# When does Angular4 HttpClient.get() return undefined?

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-http-interceptors

I am trying to test an HttpInterceptor in Angular 4. I find that when I call HttpClient.get(), it errors

TypeError: You provided 'undefined' where a stream was expected. You can provide an Observable, Promise, Array, or Iterable.

When does http.get('/data') return undefined?

[Plunkr here](http://plnkr.co/edit/AkivQzoJeJbDbv3J0Rsh?p=preview)

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { TestBed, async, inject } from '@angular/core/testing';
import { HttpClient, HttpClientModule, HttpHandler } from '@angular/common/http';
import { HttpClientTestingModule, HttpTestingController } from '@angular/common/http/testing';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/toPromise';


describe('AppComponent', () => {
    beforeEach(async(() => {
        TestBed.configureTestingModule({
            imports: [HttpClientTestingModule, HttpClientModule],
            providers: [ HttpClient, HttpHandler,
              // {
              //     provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS,
              //     useClass: AuthErrorHttpInterceptorService,
              //     multi: true
              // }
            ]
        }).compileComponents();
    }));



    it('adding header test', inject([HttpClient], (http: HttpClient) => {
        debugger;
        const httpMock = TestBed.get(HttpTestingController);

        // Make an HTTP GET request, and expect that it return an object
        // of the form {name: 'Test Data'}.
        http.get('/data')
            .subscribe(data => expect(data['name']).toEqual('Test Data'));

        // At this point, the request is pending, and no response has been
        // sent. The next step is to expect that the request happened.
        const req = httpMock.expectOne('/data');

        // If no request with that URL was made, or if multiple requests match,
        // expectOne() would throw. However this test makes only one request to
        // this URL, so it will match and return a mock request. The mock request
        // can be used to deliver a response or make assertions against the
        // request. In this case, the test asserts that the request is a GET.
        expect(req.request.method).toEqual('GET');

        // Next, fulfill the request by transmitting a response.
        req.flush({name: 'Test Data'});

        // Finally, assert that there are no outstanding requests.
        httpMock.verify();
    }));
});
```

TypeError: You provided 'undefined' where a stream was expected. You can provide an Observable, Promise, Array, or Iterable.

Edit: I have seen question [Error while unit testing HttpClientModule (Angular 4.3+)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45326952/error-while-unit-testing-httpclientmodule-angular-4-3/45331211#45331211) and imported HttpClientModule but i still get the error. Also I am not including my interceptor component until i fix this error so there issue can't be there.

Edit: `const req = httpMock.expectOne('/data');` this line never executes because the error is thrown from the line above

Edit: solution was to remove 'HttpClient, HttpHandler' from the providers array

Comment: You’re using the HTTP testing module but you never actually select the request or flush the response. Read the relevant docs: https://angular.io/guide/http#testing-http-requests

Comment: ok thanks, that might be why i am getting the error. Let me check that

Comment: Hi jonrsharpe, i edited the question with the code from the docs, but i still get the error, you provided 'undefined' where a stream was expected

Comment: when does http.get('/data') return undefined?

Comment: Please give a [mcve] with the full traceback.

Comment: http://plnkr.co/edit/AkivQzoJeJbDbv3J0Rsh?p=preview

Comment: Please read [ask], that information needs to be **in the question** - code under test, test code, traceback. Also show your research, e.g. have you read https://stackoverflow.com/a/45331211/3001761?

Answer (score 1):

FYI the final solution

```
import { AuthErrorHttpInterceptorService } from './authErrorHttpInterceptor.service';
import { TestBed, inject, fakeAsync, tick } from '@angular/core/testing';
import { RouterTestingModule } from '@angular/router/testing';
import { LoginComponent } from './../../routes/login/login.component';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { HttpHandler, HttpRequest, HTTP_INTERCEPTORS, HttpClient, HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';
import { HttpClientTestingModule, HttpTestingController } from '@angular/common/http/testing';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/catch';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { Location } from '@angular/common';

describe('AuthErrorHttpInterceptorService', () => {
    beforeEach(() => {
        TestBed.configureTestingModule({
            declarations: [LoginComponent],
            imports: [HttpClientTestingModule, HttpClientModule,
                RouterTestingModule.withRoutes([{ path: 'login', component: LoginComponent }]),
                FormsModule
            ],
            providers: [
                {
                    provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS,
                    useClass: AuthErrorHttpInterceptorService,
                    multi: true
                },
                Location
            ]
        });
    });

    // https://angular.io/guide/http#testing-http-requests
    it('subscribe should return the given data', inject([HttpClient, HttpTestingController], (http: HttpClient, httpMock: HttpTestingController) => {
        const myGet = http.get('/data');
        myGet.subscribe((data) => {
            expect(data['name']).toEqual('Test Data');
            expect(data['name']).not.toEqual('Test Datas');
        });
        const req = httpMock.expectOne('/data');
        expect(req.request.method).toEqual('GET');
        req.flush({ name: 'Test Data' });
        httpMock.verify();
    }));

    it('should redirect unauthorised requests to /api/data', inject([HttpClient, HttpTestingController], fakeAsync((http: HttpClient, httpMock: HttpTestingController) => {
        const myGet = http.get('/api/data');
        myGet.subscribe((data) => {
            expect(data['name']).toEqual('Test Data');
        }, (error) => {
            let router = TestBed.get(Router);
            let location = TestBed.get(Location);
            tick();
            expect(location.path()).toBe('/login');
        });
        const req = httpMock.expectOne('/api/data');
        expect(req.request.method).toEqual('GET');
        req.flush({ name: 'Test Data' }, { status: 401, statusText: 'Server Error' });
        httpMock.verify();
    })));

    it('should not redirect unauthorised requests to /api/authorization/data', inject([HttpClient, HttpTestingController], fakeAsync((http: HttpClient, httpMock: HttpTestingController) => {
        const myGet = http.get('/api/authorization/data');
        myGet.subscribe((data) => {
            expect(data['name']).toEqual('Test Data');
        }, (error) => {
            let router = TestBed.get(Router);
            let location = TestBed.get(Location);
            tick();
            expect(location.path()).toBe('');
        });
        const req = httpMock.expectOne('/api/authorization/data');
        expect(req.request.method).toEqual('GET');
        req.flush({ name: 'Test Data' }, { status: 401, statusText: 'Server Error' });
        httpMock.verify();
    })));

    it('should not redirect http: 200 requests to /api/data', inject([HttpClient, HttpTestingController], fakeAsync((http: HttpClient, httpMock: HttpTestingController) => {
        const myGet = http.get('/api/authorization/data');
        myGet.subscribe((data) => {
            expect(data['name']).toEqual('Test Data');
        }, (error) => {
            let router = TestBed.get(Router);
            let location = TestBed.get(Location);
            tick();
            expect(location.path()).toBe('');
        });
        const req = httpMock.expectOne('/api/authorization/data');
        expect(req.request.method).toEqual('GET');
        req.flush({ name: 'Test Data' }, { status: 200, statusText: 'success' });
        httpMock.verify();
    })));
});
```

the interceptor

```
import { Injectable, forwardRef } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpEvent, HttpInterceptor, HttpHandler, HttpRequest, HttpErrorResponse } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/do';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { Inject } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable()
export class AuthErrorHttpInterceptorService implements HttpInterceptor {
    constructor(private router: Router) { }
    intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
        return next.handle(req).do(event => { }, err => {
            if (err instanceof HttpErrorResponse
                && err.status === 401
                && !err.url.match('/api/authorization/')
                && err.url.match('/api/')) {

                this.router.navigate(['login']);
            }
        });
    }
}
```